# Calling SSRS 2008 R2 reports from Report viewer control of ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, asp.net-2.0, ssrs-2008-r2

Actually we have an application built using ASP.NET 2.0 which calls the SSRS reports 2005 from the reportviewer control of VS2005. 
Now as per the business requirement the SSRS 2005 reports were migrated to SSRS 2008 R2 reports.
Here araised the problem. We have to call the SSRS 2008 R2 reports from the same application which is built using ASP.NET 2.0.
As far as I know we are not using any authentication mechanism for alling SSRS 2005 from report viewer control of asp.net2.0. 
As there is no authentication mechanism, I simply changed the url of from SSRS2005 report server to SSRS2008 R2 server.
but I am not able to display the reports in reportviewer. It is throwing an error saying " The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized"
Is there any changes made to SSRS 2008 R2 reports in the way ASP.NET application access them or is there anything else that I should implement apart from simply changing the URL of the report server.
Please help. I am totally stuck.

Thanks,
KNSB

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation there haven't been any changes (see [2005 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983458%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) vs [2008 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983458%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

If you haven't configured any authentication, and are not providing custom credentials to the report viewer, then it will be using Windows Authentication. Someone at your organization most likely has given the corresponding user rights to use the report server (or specific folders). You will need to do so again for the new 2008 instance.